# Devise close registration but seed database with admin account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm looking to completely close off my registration system (*temporarily*) and only have 1 admin account that can be either raked into the database or seeded.

Is this possible with Devise at all? Or will a closed off registration also close off the seed/rake task with my admin user in it?

I currently have a user model with the typical devise setup, with an admin column that is a boolean - I'm currently setting that column in development by going into rails console and manually changing it.

Any help would be brilliant!

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Set-up-devise-as-a-single-user-system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a detailed step by step in the [devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Set-up-devise-as-a-single-user-system); but basically you can either skip generating the registrations routes:

```
devise_for :users, :skip => :registrations
```

Which would make it a single user system by making it impossible to register.

This requires the first user to be created with either a seed file or through the console.

Or you could create your own controller to handle registrations which cuts off after the first user:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}

# app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create
    if User.any?
      redirect_to root_path, alert: 'Only one user allowed!' and return
    end
    super
  end
end
```

Unless your seed / rake task is doing something really strange like automating a web browser then this will have no effect on your seed / rake task since they usually involve directly manipulating the DB through models and do not go though controllers at all:

```
# Example of seeding an admin user:
admin = User.create_with(surename: 'Doe', forename: 'John').find_or_create_by(email: 'admin@example.com')
admin.add_role(:admin)
```

Comment: Thanks! But how would I go about seeding an initial admin user? Through a database seed or through a custom rake task?

Comment: Extended answer with some more details about the different approaches.

Comment: Is a seed the best way to go in terms of security?

Comment: Marginally, it definitely is simpler - especially if you are doing TDD and have a bunch of tests to cover a route that only gets used once.

Comment: Of course it depends on if your app is intended to be deployed by end users who can't be asked to use a console (think wordpress here) but thats kind of an unlikely scenario for most rails apps.

Comment: Ok thanks for clearing it up. I'll create a seed and use it. End users only see posts similar to a blog.

Comment: On your seed, you have add_role(:admin), but it's not actually a role it's just a boolean field. Will this make a difference? Followed this tutorial https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3A-Add-an-Admin-Role

Comment: Nope, thats just how I usually do it with [Rolify](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to remove the devise routes for registration and still seed in the user. That user would then be able to login/logout, as long as you still have the devise routes for sessions.